# User interaction interrupted drawRect, how to solve?

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

When I drawing a UIVew rect using the drawRect function, if a user interaction happen (such as drop down a UITableView, as the picture below show), the drawing is interrupted, how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: How do you drive the drawing code? If you're using a `CADisplayLink` or a `NSTimer`, try to add it to a runloop with common mode.

Comment: I use a NSTimer to drive, OK, I will try a common mode runloop, TKS :-)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, as KudoCC said, add the NSTimer to a runloop with common mode.